# Is it safe to replace immutable data structure with Interlocked.Exchange(ref oldValue, newValue) in ASP.NET Core Web-Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, atomic

I got an api that's an end point for geographic coordinate requests. That means users can search for specific locations in their area. At the same time new locations can be added. To make the query as fast as possible, I thought I would make the R-tree unchangeable. That is, there are no locks within the R-Tree, since several threads can read at the same time, without race condition. The updates are collected and if e.g. 100 updates are collected, I want to create a new R-Tree and replace the old one. And now my question is how to do this best?

I have a SearchService, which is stored as a single tone and has an R-Tree as private instance.

In my Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<ISearchService, SearchService>();
```

ISearchService.cs

```
public interface ISearchService
{
    IEnumerable<GeoLocation> Get(RTreeQuery query);

    void Update(IEnumerable<GeoLocation> data);
}
```

SearchService.cs

```
public class SearchService : ISearchService
{
    private RTree rTree;

    public IEnumerable<GeoLocation> Get(RTreeQuery query)
    {
        return rTree.Get(query);
    }

    public void Update(IEnumerable<GeoLocation> data)
    {
        var newTree = new RTree(data);

        Interlocked.Exchange<RTree>(ref rTree, newTree);
    }
}
```

My question is, if I exchange the reference with Interlock.Exchange() the operation is atomic and there should be no race condition. But what happens if threads still use the old instance to process their request. Could it be that the garbage collector deletes the old instance when threads still access it? After all, there is no longer a reference to the old instance.

I am relatively new to this topic, so any help is welcome. Thanks for your support!

Comment: @MichaelRandall thank you for your comment. At the moment all thread use the same instance of the SearchService and therefor on the same instance of the R-Tree. Have you any advise how to solve such a problem? It would be ok if threads use a stale version. But I dont want to construct the R-Tree for each request.

Comment: @MichaelRandall so there will no problem with the garbage collector or something else? And if you like you can post it as an answer and I will accept it :). And thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @MichaelRandall without wanting to get on your nerves, but if you find the time, you can still answer the question, so that others who have a similar question have the solution right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read and writes to *references* are *atomic*, which means there will be no alignment issues. However, they could be stale.

**Section 12.6.6 of the CLI specs**

> Unless explicit layout control (see Partition II (Controlling Instance
>   Layout)) is used to alter the default behavior, data elements no
>   larger than the natural word size (the size of a native int) shall be
>   properly aligned. Object references shall be treated as though they
>   are stored in the native word size.

In regards to the GC, your trees are safe from garbage collection while they are running `Get`.

So in summary, your methods are thread safe as far as *reference atomicity* go, you can also use the `Update` method and safely overwrite the *reference*, there is no need for `Interlocked.Exchange`. The worst that can happen with your current implementation is you just get a stale tree which you have mentioned is not an issue.